# Adding native hooks dynamically

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Is there some way to add native hooks dynamically using JNI? What I mean by that is, I would like to override some methods in a class (or in a new class) so that the override calls my native code, without writing any Java code for that.

Comment: Natively, no. You could alter the class with ByteBuddy, for example, but that does not preclude "writing any Java code".

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to `native` methods, maybe registering might be the answer for you.

For example, here, I am registering native method

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL addOne(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jint a) {
  return a + 1;
}
...
...
static JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
  {"addOne",    "(I)I", (void *)&addOne}
};
...
...
(*env)->RegisterNatives(env, cls_Main,
                        methods, sizeof(methods)/sizeof(methods[0]));
```

that will be assigned to class

```
public class Main {

  public static native int addOne(int a);

  ...
  ...

}
```

Full sample: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo052

Comment: Nope, I'm not referring to that. I would like to replace a pre-existing Java method with another method, dynamically, and have that new method make a native call, without writing any Java code myself.

Comment: OK - in that case, you will have to (probably) play with `class` files and make some hacks.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible on a typical JVM, but requires defining a proxy class at runtime, from a precompiled bytecode. Unfortunately, the following method doesn't work on Android, because Dalvik uses its own bytecode format and `DefineClass` is not implemented [1]. In that case, you would have to build the package with some minimal support code written in Java and compiled to DEX.

As an example, let's say that you would like to create an AWT `Frame`, but handle window events in native code. That requires implementing the `WindowListener` interface and passing an instance to the `Frame` with `addWindowListener`.

First, implement a proxy class that forwards events to native implementation:

```java
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

class NativeWindowListener implements WindowListener
{
    public native void windowActivated(WindowEvent e);
    public native void windowClosed(WindowEvent e);
    public native void windowClosing(WindowEvent e);
    public native void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e);
    public native void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e);
    public native void windowIconified(WindowEvent e);
    public native void windowOpened(WindowEvent e);
}
```

Next, compile that class into bytecode:

```
$ javac NativeWindowListener.java
```

Use Linux command `xxd` or similar tool to convert `NativeWindowListener.class` binary into C array:

```
$ xxd -i NativeWindowListener.class
```

Embed the resulting C array into your native code and use `DefineClass` to define that class from bytecode at runtime:

```cpp
const unsigned char NativeWindowListener_class[] = { /* bytecode */ };

const jclass listener_class = jni->DefineClass(
    "NativeWindowListener", NULL,
    reinterpret_cast<const jbyte*>(NativeWindowListener_class),
    sizeof(NativeWindowListener_class));
```

Once you have a defined proxy class, you can use `RegisterNatives` to provide native implementation for the Java stubs:

```cpp
// Native event handlers
void JNICALL NativeWindowListener_windowActivated(JNIEnv* jni, jobject self, jobject event);
// etc.

#define WINDOW_EVENT_LISTENER(name)                                                     \
    {                                                                                   \
        const_cast<char*>(#name), const_cast<char*>("(Ljava/awt/event/WindowEvent;)V"), \
            reinterpret_cast<void*>(&NativeWindowListener_##name)                       \
    }

const JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
    WINDOW_EVENT_LISTENER(windowActivated),
    WINDOW_EVENT_LISTENER(windowClosed),
    WINDOW_EVENT_LISTENER(windowClosing),
    WINDOW_EVENT_LISTENER(windowDeactivated),
    WINDOW_EVENT_LISTENER(windowDeiconified),
    WINDOW_EVENT_LISTENER(windowIconified),
    WINDOW_EVENT_LISTENER(windowOpened),
};

jni->RegisterNatives(listener_class, methods, sizeof(methods) / sizeof(methods[0]));
```

Finally, you can construct the listener and pass it to the `Frame`:

```cpp
// Construct the listener
const jmethodID listener_ctor = jni->GetMethodID(listener_class, "<init>", "()V");
const jobject listener = jni->NewObject(listener_class, listener_ctor);

// Add listener to the frame
const jclass frame_class = jni->FindClass("java/awt/Frame");
const jmethodID frame_ctor = jni->GetMethodID(frame_class, "<init>", "()V");
const jmethodID frame_addwindowlistener =
    jni->GetMethodID(frame_class, "addWindowListener",
    "(Ljava/awt/event/WindowListener;)V");
const jobject frame = jni->NewObject(frame_class, frame_ctor);
jni->CallVoidMethod(frame, frame_addwindowlistener, listener);
```

If you want to store a pointer to some native context, you can add a `long` field to the listener proxy and access it with `GetFieldID` and `Get/SetLongField` JNI functions.

[1] https://github.com/android/ndk/wiki/JNI#unsupported-featuresbackwards-compatibility